# Pyspark can not convert empty array of string to array of struct

Tags: pyspark, nested

I have a very large data set that contains nested fields like array of struct elements. I would like to append new data to it every day. However, sometimes the field comes empty and Pyspark will read it as `array<string>` when the array field looks like `[]` .

I tried to cast it to array of struct but encounter this error:

```
cannot resolve due to data type mismatch: can not cast "Array<String>" to "Array<Struct>"
```

Schema Example:

```
 |--id: string (nullable = true)
 |--address: array (nullable = true)
 |   |--work: struct (containsNulll = true)
 |   |   |--country: string (nullable =true)
 |   |   |--city: string (nullable =true)
 |   |   |--street: string (nullable =true)
 | ...
```

The field in the array of struct contains hundreds of nested fields so it's hard to define the schema upon reading. Is there any way to handle such empty array case programmatically?

Comment: I ended up enforcing the field as Array<String> so that it could accept NULL and JSON strings together.